# If no sed pattern echo >> newline

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using `sed` to replace lines in conf's:

`sed -i.bak 's/^option.*/option newparam/' somefile.conf`

If my option line does not exist in somefile, how do I tell `sed` to insert it or return false?

Finally I ended up with:

`sed -i.bak "s/^#$STR.*\|^# $STR.*\|^$STR.*/$OPT/" $FILE && grep -q "^$OPT" $FILE || echo "$OPT" >> $FILE`

Comment: Tell it to unconditionally delete the option (if it finds it), and add the replacement at the end?  That assumes sequence doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Delete line(s) that begins with `option`, append (`a`) `option newparam` to last line (`$`) of the file

```
sed -i.bak '/^option/d; $ a\option newparam' somefile.conf
```

Note: since you said you want to insert the new line if `option` line doesn't exist, I assumed that where the new line is located does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use grep to check if the line exist first if it doesn't append it to the end of the file using the double pipe operator `||`. The operation will be short circuited if the first command returns true and therefor the second command is only ever executed if the first fails.

`grep -q '^option.*' file.txt || echo 'option newparam' >> file.txt`

The `-q` option suppresses the output of grep and the `||` operator will only execute the `echo` command if the `grep` command fails, that is if `$?` is not `0`. A simple example:

```
$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2 
line 3

$ grep -q 'line 4' file.txt || echo 'line not in file'
line not in file
```

The special variable `$?` contains the exit value from the previous command.

```
$ grep -q 'line 4' file.txt 

$ echo $?
1

$ grep -q 'line 3' file.txt 

$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: That's great cheers, it should work well with the sed command above.

Comment: If you could upvote all useful answers and accept the most useful that would be great! :)

Comment: Or perhaps not, as I'd like keep the file true to its original values (ie readable). Still though, it's good to know.

Comment: You have 16 rep now which is enough to upvote and accept, by accepting you will also recieve a reputation bonus, see the faq for more infomation http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You could use this method with you own `sed -i.bak` to backup the files.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this in GNU sed, preserving option order:

```
/^otheroption.*/ {
  s//otheroption newparam/       # Insert newparam
  h                              # and remember it in HS
}
$ {
  x                              # Check if option
  /^otheroption/! {              # was replaced,
    x                            # if not append it
    s/$/\notheroption newparam/  # to the last line 
  }
}
```

All on one line:

```
sed '/^option.*/ { s//option newparam/; h; }; $ { x; /^option/! { x; s/$/\noption newparam/; }; }' somefile.conf
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm after but I cannot get the code to execute although I have GNU version.

Comment: @Chrisinpants: could you provide some sample input where this doesn't work? And post it to the question.

Comment: I'm sure the code is fine, I just need to spend a bit more time with it.